# How to get exact value of range slider on mouse drop in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**I just want to get the exact value of range slider on mouse drop(release).**

```
var rangeslidervalue= $('.ex2').val();
```

I am using input type text as bootstrap slider.I have got value every time on mouse drag but i want value only on Mouse release not every time because i am hitting Ajax on when slider is drag.I have got the problem when i drag slider Ajax is hitting every time and get **ERROR Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**
Below is My slider.
[image]

My code:

```
$('sliderclass').change(function() { 
  var scrollvalue = $(this).val(); 
  var dataString = JSON.stringify({ 
    scroll:scrollvalue
  }); 
  jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    data: dataString,   
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    url: "ajax url", 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data1) {  
      console.log(data1);
    } 
  }); 
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code, since images don't help much with identifying the problem

Comment: $('sliderclass').change(function() 
  { 
  var scrollvalue = $(this).val();
  var dataString = JSON.stringify({ scroll:scrollvalue});
  jQuery.ajax({        
  type: "POST",   
  data: dataString, 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "ajax url",   
  dataType: 'json',     
  success: function(data1)
  { 
   console.log(data1);}
  });
});   
This is my code.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery UI slider than you can get value like this way

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    max: 5,
    value: 2,
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
         alert(ui.value);
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

usually, there is a `stop` callback function on slider plugin which will run when you stop dragging the element. Here is the example code of jquery ui slider for reference:

```
$( "#some_example_slider" ).slider({
    range: true, step: 50, min: 0, max: 450,
    values: [ 0, 450 ],
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var v1 = ui.values[0];
        var v2 = ui.values[1];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_file.php",
            data: "value1="+v1+"&value2="+v2,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                //do suff
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It is not working as I have tried to implement, Can you suggest me some another alternative so that I can implement that and get it resolved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use jquery UI slider